# Open URL (.mp4) in QuickTime (Cocoa App for OSX)

Tags: cocoa, nstask

I would like to open QuickTime and play a remote file.

I use the following code:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/open"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"/Applications/QuickTime Player.app", @"http://...", nil]];
[task launch];
```

But the console says:

> Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. sharedlibrary
>   apply-load-rules all

What's wrong? I also mod the third line:

```
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-a", @"/Applications/QuickTime Player.app", @"http://...", nil]];
```

I only found an answer for non native code: [How can I start QuickTime and have it start playing a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574853/how-can-i-start-quicktime-and-have-it-start-playing-a-url)

Thanks very much for some hints or samples!

Comment: The second version is correct; the first version will open QuickTime Player and then open the document in some random app. I can't see anything wrong with this code, so most probably the crash was elsewhere—what made you single this code out in particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: Using ASBQuickTimeApplication.

Comment: Is that third-party code or do you mean you're using the Scripting Bridge? Either way, you don't need such a heavyweight solution. Actually, you don't even need NSTask: You can open a document in a specific application using Launch Services or NSWorkspace.